# IText 5.5.11 parseElements with encoding and correct css styles

Tags: character-encoding, itext

Hi guys I am using Itext 5.5.11 to parse elements from html string to pdf which should be structured with 3 columns layout. This html string I cannot edit (one in code is just for example). I am struggling with encoding to set it to "cp1250" because of chars such as č, ž, ř etc. Thanks in advance.

```
private Rectangle[] COLUMNS = {new Rectangle(36, 36, 200, 780),
                     new Rectangle(216, 36, 380, 780),
                     new Rectangle(396, 36, 559, 780)}; 

public byte[] generateMultiColumnPDF() {

        Document document = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            FontFactory.register(timesFontPath, "times");
            FontFactory.register(timesBoldFontPath, "times-bold");

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdf);
            writer.setPageEvent(this);

            document.open();        

            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(canvas);

            int sideOfThePage = 0;
            columnText.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[sideOfThePage]);

            StringBuilder testHtml = new StringBuilder();
            testHtml.append("<h1>H1</h1>");
            testHtml.append("<h2>H2</h2>");
            testHtml.append("<h3>H3</h3>");
            testHtml.append("<h4>H4</h4>");
            testHtml.append("<p>testovací paragraf so speciálními znaky č ř ž </p>");

            StringBuilder cssStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            cssStringBuilder.append("body {font-size: 8px; font-family: times} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("p {font-size: 8px; font-family: times; line-height: 10px} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("h1 {font-size: 14px; font-family: times} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("h2 {font-size: 12px; font-family: times} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("h3 {font-size: 9px; font-family: times} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("h4 {font-size: 8px; font-family: times} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("li {line-height: 10px; font-family: times} ");
            cssStringBuilder.append("a {color: green} ");

            ArrayList<Element> objects = parseToElementList(testHtml.toString(), cssStringBuilder.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                columnText.addElement(objects.get(i));

                while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(columnText.go())) {

                    if (sideOfThePage == 0) {
                        sideOfThePage = 1;
                    } else if (sideOfThePage == 1) {
                        sideOfThePage = 2;
                    } else {
                        sideOfThePage = 0;
                        document.newPage();
                    }

                    columnText.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[sideOfThePage]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        document.close();
        return pdf.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: The standard Type 1 fonts don't support the characters you need. You should (1.) use another font program (currently, you're using `times.afm` which is just a font metrics file, you should use `times.ttf` instead), and (2.) use a `FontProvider` that tells XML Worker to use the `.ttf` font program instead of the `.afm` metrics. If iText 5 were still supported, I'd write you an example, but since that's much more work than just using iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on, I prefer asking you to upgrade.

Comment: Actually I was still recently using old Itext 2.x.x with MultiColumnText and StyeSheet classes where I could load tag style encoding for body. Just few days ago I started using Flying Saucer 9.12 with support for Itext 5, if you would know how to replace it so I could use Itext 7 I would be thankful.